# Flutter: How to listen changes inside the list which is in model using provider?

Tags: flutter

I am trying to handle a model which has a list but I stucking in between I am not getting any idea how to handle list which is in my model first of all I am getting data from api and I am storing Jason object in my model which is working perfect following is my json model

```
{
    "statusCode": 200,
    "success": true,
    "messages": [],
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 35,
            "title": "Astrology",
            "filename": "Astrology.jpg",
            "mimetype": "image/jpeg",
            "directcalling": 1,
            "parentid": null,
            "subcat": []
        },
        {
            "id": 36,
            "title": "Muhurtam",
            "filename": "Muhurtam.jpg",
            "mimetype": "image/jpeg",
            "directcalling": 1,
            "parentid": null,
            "subcat": [
                {
                    "id": 50,
                    "title": "abc",
                    "filename": "abc.png",
                    "mimetype": "image/png",
                    "directcalling": 0,
                    "parentid": 36,
                    "subcat": []
                }
```

now I am Saving  above json object  in below model following is my model class

```
class Data {
  Data({
    this.id,
    required this.title,
    required this.filename,
    required this.mimetype,
    required this.directcalling,
    this.parentid,
    this.subcat,
  });
  late final int? id;
  late final String title;
  late final String filename;
  late final String mimetype;
  late final int directcalling;
  late final Null parentid;
  late final List<Subcat>? subcat;

  Data.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    title = json['title'];
    filename = json['filename'];
    mimetype = json['mimetype'];
    directcalling = json['directcalling'];
    parentid = null;
    subcat = List.from(json['subcat']).map((e) => Subcat.fromJson(e)).toList();
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final _data = <String, dynamic>{};
    // _data['id'] = id;
    _data['title'] = title;
    _data['filename'] = filename;
    // _data['mimetype'] = mimetype;
    _data['directcalling'] = directcalling;
    // _data['parentid'] = parentid;
    // _data['subcat'] = subcat.map((e) => e.toJson()).toList();
    return _data;
  }
}

class Subcat {
  Subcat({
    this.id,
    required this.title,
    required this.filename,
    required this.mimetype,
    required this.directcalling,
    this.parentid,
    this.subcat,
  });
  late final int? id;
  late final String title;
  late final String filename;
  late final String mimetype;
  late final int directcalling;
  late final int? parentid;
  late final List<dynamic>? subcat;

  Subcat.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    title = json['title'];
    filename = json['filename'];
    mimetype = json['mimetype'];
    directcalling = json['directcalling'];
    parentid = json['parentid'];
    subcat = List.castFrom<dynamic, dynamic>(json['subcat']);
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final _data = <String, dynamic>{};
    //_data['id'] = id;
    _data['title'] = title;
    _data['filename'] = filename;
    //_data['mimetype'] = mimetype;
    _data['directcalling'] = directcalling;
    //_data['parentid'] = parentid;
    //_data['subcat'] = subcat;
    return _data;
  }
}
```

I am updating particular id in list:subcat which is in my Data class now I want to show changes to user after updating following is my update function

```
Data findById(int id) {
    return categories!.data.firstWhere((cat) => cat.id == id);
  }
Future<void> updateCatAtributes(
      int id, BuildContext context, Subcat newCat, Data subid) async {
    print('updating....${newCat.toJson()}');
    final catIndex = subid.subcat!.indexWhere((prod) => prod.id == id);
    if (catIndex >= 0) {
      subid.subcat![catIndex] = newCat;
      notifyListeners();
    } else {
      print('...');
    }
```

following is my dropdown widget where I want to display changed title in my menu item

```
final loadedProduct = Provider.of<Category>(
      context,
      listen: false,
    ).findById(catId);
Consumer<Category>(
              builder: (context, value, child) {
                return Column(
                  children: [
                    DropdownButton<String>(
                      elevation: 16,
                      isExpanded: true,
                      hint: Text('please select sub category'),
                      items: loadedProduct.subcat!.map((v) {
                        return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                            onTap: () {
                              subcat = v.id;

                              _initValues = {
                                'title': v.title,
                              };
                            },
                            value: v.title,
                            child: Text(v.title));
                      }).toList(),
                      onChanged: (val) {
                        value.updatesubcat(val!);
                        print(val);
                      },
                      value: value.sub,
                    ),
                  ],
```

Comment: Show us your UI code.

Comment: updated my question please check

Comment: wehre you define loadedProduct ?

Comment: updated my question with loaded product and find by id catid is getting from my arguments while navigating